# Adding value to dropdownbox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my client code:

```
<li>choose file: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList id="chooseFileDropDown" runat="server" /></li>
```

This is my codebehind:

```
ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
listItem.Text = "Test";
chooseFileDropDown.Items.Add(listItem);
```

I have also tried:

```
chooseFileDropDown.items.Add("Test");
```

And also:

```
List<ListItem> listItem = new List<ListItem>();
listItem.Add(new ListItem("Test"));
chooseFileDropDown.Items.Add(listItem.ToString());
```

None of the above code works. The dropdownbox does not get any values. What am I doing wrong?
My code gets loaded in the:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    chooseFileDropDown.Items.Add("Test"); 
}
```

Comment: If it gets loaded in `Page_Load` why dont you show the complete `Page_Load`?

Comment: add appendDataBounds="true" in your dropdown tag

Comment: @user1848739: OP hasn't mentioned that he also uses a `DataSource`. However, so long as we don't see his code we can only guess.

Comment: So is this the only place where you add items or assign a `DataSource`? Does `Page_Load` gets executed at all? What is the context of this `DropDownList`, does it sit in another databound webcontrol like repeater or gridview or in a `UserControl`?

Comment: Yes it get's loaded when the aspx page is called, which i do manually right now. Right now I just click on a link to open this page, then the dropdownbox should be filled on page_load

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chooseFileDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Add New", ""));
```

If you want to add on top:

```
ListItem lst = new ListItem ( "Add New" , "0" );
chooseFileDropDown.Items.Insert(chooseFileDropDown.Items.Count-1 ,lst);
```